# Get position of token in berts output layer

Tags: huggingface-transformers

We are interested in the bert vectors for each token. With bert vector we mean the word vector for a specific token in berts output layer. So we would like to find out which token produces which bert vector. We wrote some code but we are not sure if it is correct or how to test it.

So in the code we process a sentence with bert. We construct a list of position ids and hand them to the model. Afterwards we use the same position ids to map the tokens to the output layer. Then there is some code that produces calculates the character offsets of each vector in the input sentence.

Is this the correct way how to use position_ids to generate

```py
from transformers import BertModel, BertConfig, BertTokenizer
import torch

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

def sentence_to_vector(input_sentence):
    tokens_encoded = tokenizer.encode(input_sentence, add_special_tokens=True)
    input_ids = torch.tensor(tokens_encoded).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1

    seq_length = input_ids.size(1)

    # code to construct position_ids from here: 
    # https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/8da280ebbeca5ebd7561fd05af78c65df9161f92/pytorch_pretrained_bert/modeling.py#L188:L189
    position_ids = torch.arange(seq_length, dtype=torch.long, device=input_ids.device)  
    position_ids = position_ids.unsqueeze(0).expand_as(input_ids)
    outputs = model(input_ids, position_ids=position_ids)

    tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_ids[0])
    # from the BertModel documentation (example at the bottom):
    # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
    # https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertModel

    #ttv = {}  # token to vector
    #for i in position_ids[0]:
    #    ttv[tokens[i]] = outputs[0][0][position_ids[0][i]]

    data = []
    last_offset = 0
    for i in range(0, len(position_ids[0])):
        token = tokens[position_ids[0][i]]
        vector = outputs[0][0][position_ids[0][i]]
        pos_begin = None
        pos_end = None
        if not token == "[CLS]" and not token == "[SEP]":
            pos_begin = input_sentence.find(token, last_offset)
            pos_end = pos_begin + len(token)
            last_offset = pos_end
        data.append({
            "token": token,
            "pos_begin": pos_begin,
            "pos_end": pos_end,
            "vector": vector
        })
    return data

input_sentence = "do the chicken dance!"
data = sentence_to_vector(input_sentence)

for token in data:
    print(token["token"] + "\t" + str(token["pos_begin"]) + "\t" + str(token["pos_end"]) + "\t" + str(token["vector"][0:3]) + "..." )
```